# Problem with same network in my site

Tags: switch, router

I've got a problem in my site
Many members could not enter the site 
[dasolo.org](http://www.dasolo.org/) from italy
The problem is that some people walk in are also using the same network from Italy
I use, for example, infostrada network And I enter normal from the city of Naples and others have infostrada and can not enter from Rome
A network  3g can not be used by entering
My Website is not blocked
I worked to convert him from another site 'dasolo.info. and the first site was blocked in Italy
But this 'dasolo.org' is not blocked and I enter normal fromitaly ..
In your opinion, what is the problem???
thank u for help
dasolo.org

Comment: Questions about networks over which you have no control, and questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 (DNS), are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Your question appears to fall outside the areas that our community decided are on topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-t opic) for more details. This is either a server problem or a problem on networks over which you have not control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to troubleshoot in some way.

1. I think you first need to make a DNS resolution i guess, from the site that your are not be able to enter.

nslookup(if you are using windows) or dig(linux):
nslookup dasolo.org

And see if you succefull get the ip address of that site. If not, you need to contact with your service provider and clear that.

2. If the first is good, you need to sniff your network traffic with wireshark or something like that to see what´s happening when you tried to entablish a connecting to that site.